# J2ME Native Mp3 Player - to play mp3 files larger than 1.5 MB

Tags: java, java-me, mp3

I am trying a play 5mb Mp3 file using the following code in J2me devices.

```
 InputStream myInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Test.mp3");
   Player myPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(myInputStream, "audio/mpeg");
   myInputStream.close(); // Closing inputStream after creating Player object.
   myPlayer.realize();
   myPlayer.prefetch();
   myPlayer.start();
```

This code works for mp3 file below 1.5 MB but not working for larger files.Does any one how actually the native mp3 players in devices playing mp3 files.

Comment: what exception you are getting while playing large file

Comment: Have you tried not closing the input stream? Maybe the player only buffers the first 1.5 MB and then tries to read on, but it can't since the stream is closed?

Comment: dont close input stream because player can not read after stream is closed

Answer (score 0):

The low end J2ME devices or low memory devices can play maximum of 1.5 MB of size songs thru the programming.